# how to display JSON DATA in Label in Xamarin form with Rest Post Method in api

Tags: json, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "data": {
        "userId": "40",
        "userName": "Madhu",
        "password": "123456",
        "fullName": "Balaji",
        "dateCreated": "2019-08-03 10:36:20",
        "districtID": "chennai"}}
```

my answer should be
welcome Madhu
your id is 40

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you please post more details about this question ,e.g. Did you have a problem parsing Json  data or displaying it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# classes to represent your JSON-object:

```
public class Data
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
    public string dateCreated { get; set; }
    public string districtID { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }

    public static RootObject FromJson(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    }
}
```

To get object of `RootObject` class from incoming JSON-string:

```
var myRootObject = RootObject.FromJson(json);
```

Then in your View's code-behind (I prefer bindings though) use `Text` property from `Label` class (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.label.text?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Label_Text)):

```
yourLabel.Text = $"welcome {myRootObject.Data.userName} your id is {myRootObject.Data.userId}";
```